# Resolve dpkg was interrupted

Tags: raspbian-jessie, dpkg

I'm still very much a newbie, so please be gentle with me.

We had a power cut while running `apt-get dist-upgrade` [Raspian Jessie]
.

When the power came back on, I ran `apt-get dist-upgrade` again but got

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

The manual run of dpkg showed:

```
Setting up libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:armhf (2.28.2-1rpi4rpi1) ...
```

and then the pi then hangs.

I Removed all the files inside `/var/lib/dpkg/updates` 
and ran `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` again.

Same result and the pi hangs.

Is there a super-hero out there that knows how I resolve this?

Comment: How long did you leave it for?

Comment: Interesting you should ask that. I was wondering if I was being impatient. I left it for about 35 minutes. I also found that the network connection is lost after a few seconds. This made me think that the pi had stopped.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [Upgrade or install using apt-get results in dpkg error](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/85308/79866). Try the suggestions on that answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you exactly what to do.

`dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`

Comment: I believe this is what Rob did in the bit starting with "The manual run of dpkg showed", but it is hanging; that's the problem that this question is asking about.

Comment: Thank you Aurora0001 that is exactly my problem. I already did as the error message instructed. It started the first process and hung. So can anybody tell me if or how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Removing power while the Pi is actively updating can cause a wide range of damage to your filesystem.

If following the instruction does not resolve the issue I suggest you restore from your backup. This is what most of us would do.

It is always prudent to make a backup before major updates on ANY computer, not just the Pi.

You could try `sudo apt-get clean` but repairing these issues is far from simple.

In some cases purging and re-installing damaged packages can help.

PS Jessie in no longer supported. If you have to re-install you would be better to install Stretch.

Comment: Do a file-system check to check file-system. Note this may not be the problem. For the future configure the File-system to be fully journaled. This will make it (the file-system) more robust to power off.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Raspbian is journalled by default, and automatically checks on boot. Journalling **IS NOT** a protection for all errors.

Comment: @Milliways thank you for your advice. I would love to restore from a backup, but last year made my brain go fuzzy (holding hands with a loved one through chemotherapy can do that to you) and relevant back ups don't exist. Hence the need to try and sort this in a simple way (brain still fuzzy). The unfuzzy part of my brain is worried that I will just make things worse!!!!